# IoC Deciding specific implemetation at runtime

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I would like to implement some inversion of control in my framework.

So I have an interface `GenericDatabase` that defines the methods that have to be implemented. I do not know in advance which classes will implement this, but I have the methods that will call the interface methods. So at runtime I need to read, from a configuration file, which specific implementation should be used (otherwise, I would have to know all potential implementation classes that a user might use). I have read some Martin Fowler articles but did not clear the issue up.

How can I achieve this?

I guess I am trying something like:

```
GenericDatabase database = Class.forName("com.example.myCustomDatabase").newInstance();
```

Also with the handicap that it should be inside the try-with-resources:

```
try (GenericDatabase database = Class.forName("com.example.myCustomDatabase").newInstance()) {
```

Comment: Why don't you use an existing IoCC for this task? e.g. Spring

Comment: I need to know how to do it myself. Using Spring, Pico, etc. will not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, and I might be wrong, I think the right way is:

```
try (GenericDatabase database = (GenericDatabase) Class.forName("com.example.myCustomDatabase").newInstance()) {
```

with:

```
public interface GenericDatabase extends AutoCloseable {
```

where `com.example.myCustomDatabase` is read from a configuration file.